Erasing solid color background from behind a transparent object
I would like to erase solid color background from a picture like this:

Representation of result as it would appear in graphics editing software:

Is there a straight forward way to do this in Magick.NET, ImageMagick or maybe even System.Drawing.Common?
I am fine with the object being single color instead of grayscale, as I can just repeat the process for black and white pixels separately.
I already learned how to apply composite operators, filters like grayscale and such.
Something like ImageMagick's level-colors looks like it might do the job but I am failing at trying to work with the operators.
I also know that as a last resort I can do some pixel math manually like this
foreach (var pixel in magickImageClone.GetPixels())
{

}

but I am trying to avoid to do so.
Honestly I can't do much more than trial and error here because Magick.NET function names like OutDst don't really tell me me much.

In Imagemagick 6 command line (sorry I do not know C#), try

convert img.png -colorspace gray -alpha copy result.png


Is that what you want?
If on Imagemagick 7, change convert to magick.
